# How to record/track onTouch coordinates of the past X seconds?

Tags: android, arrays, coordinates, seconds, ontouch

I have a custom view in Android which contains an onDraw along with onTouchEvent method and I'd like to record **all the touched X coordinates of the past 2 seconds.** What I had in mind is a simple float array, thats being populated by motionEvent.getX() but I've got no clue how to afterwards delete the "old" coordinates or even how to initialize a such dynamic array.

Answer (score 0):

First what you will want to do is create a custom wrapper object that will hold touches X/Y coordinates as well as a time stamp that the coordinates. An example would theoretically look like this:

```
public class TouchRecord {
float x;
float y;
long expiry = -1L;

/**
 * Default constructor taht will not set an expiration time.
 * @param x
 * @param y
 */
public TouchRecord(float x, float y) {
    this.x = x;
    this.y = y;
}

/**
 * Overloaded constructor that will handle setting up the touch record expiration time.
 *
 * @param x
 * @param y
 * @param millisToExpiry
 */
public TouchRecord(float x, float y, long recieved, long millisToExpiry) {
    this.x = x;
    this.y = y;
    // Store the time this touch record should be expired based on the current uptime and the
    // milliseconds in the touch record is valid.
    this.expiry = SystemClock.uptimeMillis() + millisToExpiry;
}

public float getY() {
    return y;
}

public float getX() {
    return x;
}

public boolean hasExpired() {
    // If the expiry value hasn't been set always return false.
    return (expiry != -1 ? (SystemClock.uptimeMillis() >= expiry): false);
}
```

}

Then inside of your custom view's onTouchEvent(MotionEvent) you listen for the MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN action and create a new TouchRecord obj and pass in the the X, Y, and the expiration values into the constructor and add the obj into an ArrayList since it can dynamically resize on command (This is necessary because the system can get flooded with dozen of touch events really quickly and it hard to know exactly how many you will receive in 2 seconds). Prepare a Handler that will indefinitely execute a runnable every 2 seconds (or even less if you want your touch records to remain as accurate and up-to-date as possible), that will iterate over all of the TouchRecords and remove all expired indexes.